# Symbol.hasInstance returns false on custom object

Tags: arrays, typescript, symbols

TypeScript playground fails on `Symbol.hasInstance` builtin symbol but works for others.

Tried other symbol methods `Symbol.match`, `Symbol.replace` work perfectly fine and `Symbol.hasInstance` is identified correctly as shown in console.log

Tried on both typescript playground and MDN both return false with generated code.

TypeScript code as in playground, you can paste the below in 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

```
class Array1 {
    static [Symbol.hasInstance](instance) {
    console.log(instance);
    return Array.isArray(instance);
  }
}
console.log(Symbol.hasInstance.toString());
let arr: string[] = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(arr instanceof Array1);
console.log([] instanceof Array1);
// expected output: true
// output is false
```

Generated code fails to return true on left hand side when you click run

```
var Array1 = /** @class */ (function () {
     function Array1() {
    }
    Array1[Symbol.hasInstance] = function (instance) {
        console.log(instance);
        return Array.isArray(instance);
    };
    return Array1;
}());
console.log(Symbol.hasInstance.toString());
var arr = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(arr instanceof Array1);
console.log([] instanceof Array1);
```

Should return true instead of false

Answer (score 0):

The official playground doesn't allow you to change too many of the compiler options. In particular, it seems to target ES5, but `Symbol.hasInstance` was only available in `ES2015` and later. If you use that as a target, it generates code that works. Try it [here](https://typescript-play.js.org/?noImplicitAny=false&target=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBO8wE8CM0DeAoavoQBcwCBLYaAbQGVkBbAIwHsQA6AC0gEkA7Qsb4AFMAugAoSvIgMEBKTDjzBGvZoJYhGAc3GT+QmQG4FueIIIBXeNziIULEhARJkOvtMMKAvlm9KVINQ1tGgZmdi5daRYCRioCeAltGQ8AgmgwRAAufHjEimFoAF5KAHIwEoAaaBL6EuEjPwhVdS1RDPhoCTchRgAzG2dUQyA).

But how can you get it to generate working code even when targetting ES5? I'm not sure why you would need to because `Symbol.hasInstance` simply won't work in engines that don't support it, but here's TypeScript that will also generate working JavaScript in the official playground:

```
class Array1 { }
Object.defineProperty(Array1, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    get: () => (instance) => {
        console.log(instance);
        return Array.isArray(instance);
    }
});
console.log(Symbol.hasInstance.toString());
let arr: string[] = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(arr instanceof Array1);
```